# Template method of the template class

Tags: c++, templates

I have this declarations in my header file:

```
template<class T>
class list {
protected:
    struct Node{...}
public:
...
template<typename Predicate>
Node* find_if(const Predicate& pred);
...
};
```

And after class declaration I have find_if method definition (in the same file):

```
template<class T, typename Predicate>
typename list<T>::Node* list<T>::find_if(const Predicate& pred) {...}
```

But MSVC compiler is "unable to match function definition to an existing declaration"
Why my method definition is wrong?
Thanks for help

Comment: It must be `template<class T> template <typename Predicate> typename list<T>::Node* list<T>::find_if(const Predicate& pred) {...}` I.e. you have to repeat the nested templates in the external definition.

Answer (score 1):

For nested templates and external definition, the approach of OP is not correct.

Correct is:

```
template<class T>
template <typename Predicate>
typename list<T>::Node* list<T>::find_if(const Predicate& pred) { ... }
```

I.e. each template has to be written separately.

Demo:

```
template<class T>
class list {
protected:
    struct Node { };
public:

  template<typename Predicate>
  Node* find_if(const Predicate& pred);

};

#if 0 // OPs attempt: Syntax error.

template<class T, typename Predicate>
typename list<T>::Node* list<T>::find_if(const Predicate& pred);

#else // Correct:

template<class T>
template <typename Predicate>
typename list<T>::Node* list<T>::find_if(const Predicate& pred) { return nullptr; }

#endif // 0

int main()
{
  list<int> intList;
}
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ec494fbc1bf37c5)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to see that your definition cannot be right is that you didn't declare any template with two parameters. The correct syntax is

```
template <class T>
template <typename Predicate>
typename list<T>::Node* list<T>::find_if(const Predicate& pred) {}
```